# How to detect when a user, and only a user scrolls an NSScrollView

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsscrollview, nsscroller

Does anyone know a way to detect when an `NSScrollView` is scrolled by user input, and only user input)?

The reason I want to do this is because I have a `NSScrollView` with a `contentView` that is continuously increasing it's width.  I want the `NSScrollView` to 'lock' onto the right hand end of the contentView (i.e. track it) if the user scrolls to the right hand end of the contentView and I want the 'lock' to be released when the user (and only the scrolls) scrolls aways from the right hand end.

The closest I had to getting to this to work was by observing the `NSViewBoundsDidChangeNotification` and changing a 'lock' variable, as shown here:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
(...)
    if (lockToEnd) {
        NSLog(@"xAxisView at end");
        NSPoint newScrollOrigin;
        newScrollOrigin.y = 0;
        newScrollOrigin.x = [self frame].size.width - [[self enclosingScrollView] bounds].size.width;
        [self scrollPoint:newScrollOrigin];
    }
}

-(void)SWXAxisViewDidScroll:(NSNotification *)note{
    NSLog(@"XAxisDidScroll: %@",note);
    if ([[[self enclosingScrollView] horizontalScroller] floatValue] > 0.97){
        lockToEnd = YES;
    } else {
        lockToEnd = NO;
    }
}
```

However, this was not appropriate because an `NSViewBoundsDidChangeNotification` is sent anytime the bounds are changed, and thus when the bounds of the `contentView` increase, the `NSScroller` reduces it's `floatValue` and my observing method is called.  EVen if I set the `NSScroller`'s `floatValue` to 1.0, it is reset to 0.0 when the `bounds.size.width` of the `contentView` first exceeds the `bounds.size.width` of the `NSScrollView`.  Thus, I can't tell if the `NSViewBoundsDidChangeNotification` was sent because the user scrolled or because the `contentView` got wider.

I have considered subclassing `NSScroller` and using the `mouseDown:` and `mouseDragged:` methods to track user input and update my lock variable.  However, my concern is that these methods will not be called if the user swipes their trackpad to scroll.  Another smaller concern, which I think is probably unfounded, is that it might break the `NSScrollView`<->`NSScroller` relationship and I would have to re-implement a lot of scrolling features.

Have I missed a simpler way to do this?  It seems like I should be able to do this because documents do it all the time?  Are my concerns about subclassing `NSScroller` valid?

Comment: Of I realised just after posting that calling [super mouseDown:...] and [super mouseDragged:..] would probably solve and concerns I had about breaking the NSScroller<->NSScrollView relationship.

Comment: Except I was wrong.  Sending a mouseDown or mouseDragged message to super cancels out the rest of the method, whether you call it at the end or the start.  Not sending these messages breaks the NSScroller.

Comment: Is it a problem with subclassing an NSControl?